# More than 2 menus in a single activity in Sliding Menu (jfeinstein10)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Is it possible to have attached in one activity more than 2 SlidingMenu objects? Triggered by different buttons?

What I'm planning is have a bottom action bar, so I have all 4 corners of the screen with buttons. I want each of those to trigger or toggle a different SlidingMenu with different content.

I already have the top 2, but I'm missing bottom 2 because when I try to instantiate them I have no errors, error is when I call `.setMenu()` method in the last 2 (bottom ones).

Is what I am planning to do, possible? And if it is, how do I achieve it?

```
sMenuLeft = new SlidingMenu(this);
sMenuLeft.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
sMenuLeft.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
sMenuLeft.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
sMenuLeft.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
sMenuLeft.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_100_offset);
sMenuLeft.setFadeEnabled(false);
sMenuLeft.setBehindScrollScale(0.0f);
sMenuLeft.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
sMenuLeft.setMenu(foo);
sMenuLeft.setSecondaryMenu(foo2);

sMenuRight = new SlidingMenu(this);
sMenuRight.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
sMenuRight.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
sMenuRight.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
sMenuRight.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow_right);
sMenuRight.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_50_offset);
sMenuRight.setFadeEnabled(false);
sMenuRight.setBehindScrollScale(0.0f);
sMenuRight.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
sMenuRight.setMenu(foo3); // Error is here
sMenuRight.setSecondaryMenu(foo4); // And I suppose here as well
```

**UPDATE:**

LogCat Shows this:

```
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.aktio.moveo/co.aktio.moveo.android.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2049)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4722)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:370)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at co.aktio.moveo.android.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:140)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4539)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2013)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    ... 11 more
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
07-19 19:15:29.203: E/AndroidRuntime(30038):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Posted already. have you tried it?